# Changing the qedsymbol to a personal icon

Tags: math-mode, graphics, symbols

When I write out my own proofs by hand on paper, I use my own personal variant of Q.E.D. / square to finish out the proofs (its a cursive version of my initials).

I've doodled up this icon on paint and want to insert it into my proof environments in the end as its Q.E.D. symbol.

I know how to change the symbol to whatever using

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{text here}
```

But I don't know how to extend this to use an image file rather than text. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be as simple as

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\includegraphics[height=1ex]{<image>}}
```

where you can specify the options to suit your needs.

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\includegraphics[height=1ex]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  This is a theorem proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much! If you don't mind, do you have any idea of how to make the \qedsymbol create a new line for the symbol and place it on that as to avoid extending the line height too much?

Comment: @wjmccann: You could consider `\smash`ing a too-large symbol. Something like `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\smash{\includegraphics[<opts>]{<img>}}}`.