# Redefining the symbol for the end of proof to \blackbox

Tags: proof-package

In a `.cls` file, which is referenced by my latex code, I have the following definition for the end of proof symbol:

```
\newcommand\qedsymbol{\hbox{\rlap{$\sqcap$}$\sqcup$}}
\newcommand\qed{\relax\ifmmode\else\unskip\quad\fi\qedsymbol}
\newcommand\smartqed{\renewcommand\qed{\relax\ifmmode\qedsymbol\else{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\qedsymbol\parfillskip=\z@\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}\fi}}
```

Can somebody please explain what is happening here, and how should I change it, so that I can just have the black box symbol (■) at the end of the proofs.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.7ex}{0.7ex}}`

Comment: `\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blackbox$}`; related/duplicate: [Changing the `\qedsymbol` to a personal icon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529052/5764)